# Code isn't uploading but printing in console

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I've made this code, and it should upload something but instead it doesn't upload anything and just prints the outcome of the command in my console, and doesn't upload anything to the website

```
import requests, os, re, subprocess
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

command = 'netsh interface ip show addresses "Ethernet" | findstr /c:IP'
outcome = str(subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True).wait())
#soup = BeautifulSoup(outcome,'lxml')

#outcome = outcome.replace('0','')

#print str(subprocess.call(command, shell=True))

requests.post("example.com", {'field1': outcome})
```

and the console output:

```
IP Address:                           192.168.1.23
```

Which uploads to the website 0

and I tried:

```
import requests, os, re, subprocess
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

command = 'netsh interface ip show addresses "Ethernet" | findstr /c:IP'
#subprocess.communicate(command, shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True).communicate()
outcome = subprocess.PIPE
#soup = BeautifulSoup(outcome,'lxml')

#outcome = outcome.replace('0','')

#print str(subprocess.call(command, shell=True))

requests.post("example.com", {'field1': outcome})
```

and the console output:

```
IP Address:                           192.168.1.23
```

Which uploads to the website -1

What I want it to do is to upload that ip address outcome to a website.

Comment: Nothing in this code should print anything that I can see. How do you obtain the "outcome"?

Comment: @roganjosh Well, it should upload the outcome to the website, but it prints it in my console where I execute the script from. Im using python2.7 if it makes any difference

Comment: @roganjosh I edited the quistion, please see what you can do

Answer (score 0):

You don’t use subprocess correctly. I suggest you use `subprocess.Popen.communicate`, and pass in stdout=subprocess.PIPE to actually obtain the stdout of your subprocess.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["my", "command"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, _ = p.communicate()
```

Comment: I doesnt work. I get the following error `subprocess.communicate(command, shell=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'communicate'`